# User Management System: a web app for management of user records (Part I: Backend)

Tags: java

***Note:** It's Part I of the User Management System project, focused on the backend. See Part II [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/291088/user-management-system-a-web-app-for-management-of-user-records-part-ii-front).*

I made this app about a year ago. I was a fledgling developer who didn't have a lot of clues to what he was doing but who nevertheless tried to do his best. For developers with decades of experience behind them, this sentence may sound amusing, but for me that time feels like ages ago.

Anyway, it's a rather old-fashioned web app with backend and frontend merged together, plain HTML, clumsy JavaScript, but I still believe the UI was quite pretty. I have improved as a backend developer, but I'm much rustier as a frontend guy and wouldn't be able to write a UI half as complex.

I didn't refactor it. This project is a snapshot of what I was back then (except for Docker and README which I added months later). It's still on the front page of my GitHub, though.

Clone [the repo](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/291088/user-management-system-a-web-app-for-management-of-user-records-part-ii-front), if you don't feel like copy-pasting it. The repo includes an illustrated README. If you actually going to run it, I strongly suggest you follow the guidelines in the README file (which are, essentially, "clone and run the compose").

```java
package pp.users;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class UserManagementSystemApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserManagementSystemApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```java
package pp.users.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import pp.users.model.Role;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import java.util.function.Function;

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig {
    @Bean
    // you need to see Part II to see where it's used
    public Function<Set<Role>, String> jsonify() {
        return s -> {
            StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",\n", "[\n", "\n]");
            for (Role role : s) {
                sj.add(String.format("{\n\"id\" : %d,\n\"authority\" : \"%s\"\n}", role.getId(), role.getAuthority()));
            }
            return sj.toString();
        };
    }
}
```

```java
package pp.users.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import pp.users.dao.UserDao;
import pp.users.model.User;

@Configuration
@Import(WebMvcConfig.class)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final UserDao userDao;

    public WebSecurityConfig(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("USER")
                .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin()
                .successHandler(successHandler())
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> {
            User user = userDao.findByUsername(username);
            if (user == null) {
                String message = String.format("No user with username %s is found in the database", username);
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(message);
            }
            return user;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        return (httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, authentication) ->
                httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/");
    }
}
```

```java
package pp.users.controller;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import pp.users.model.Role;
import pp.users.model.User;
import pp.users.service.RoleService;
import pp.users.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class MyController {
    private final UserService userService;

    private final RoleService roleService;

    public MyController(UserService userService, RoleService roleService) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.roleService = roleService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model, Authentication authentication) {
        User loggedUser = userService.findLoggedUser(authentication);
        String loggedUserUsername = loggedUser.getUsername();
        Role userRole = roleService.findRoleByName("USER");

        model.addAttribute("loggedUser", loggedUser)
                .addAttribute("users", userService.findAllExceptLoggedUser(loggedUserUsername))
                .addAttribute("newUser", new User(userRole))
                .addAttribute("adminRoleSet", roleService.findAdminRoleSet());
        return "home-page";
    }
}
```

```java
package pp.users.controller;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import pp.users.model.User;
import pp.users.service.UserService;

@RestController
public class MyRestController {
    private final UserService userService;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public MyRestController(UserService userService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @PostMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity<User> addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        String userPassBeforeEncoding = user.getPassword();
        String encodedPass = passwordEncoder.encode(userPassBeforeEncoding);
        user.setPassword(encodedPass);
        userService.save(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PatchMapping("/users/{username}")
    public void disableEnableUserByUsername(@PathVariable String username,
                                            @RequestHeader String patch_type) {
        if (patch_type.equals("disable")) {
            userService.disableUserByUsername(username);
        } else if (patch_type.equals("enable")) {
            userService.enableUserByUsername(username);
        }
    }

    @PutMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(@RequestBody User user, @RequestHeader String password_change) {
        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(password_change)) {
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        }
        userService.save(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/users/{username}")
    public void deleteUserByUsername(@PathVariable String username) {
        userService.deleteUserByUsername(username);
    }
}
```

```java
package pp.users.dao;


import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import pp.users.model.Role;

import java.util.List;

public interface RoleDao extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {
    Role findByAuthority(String authority);

    List<Role> findByAuthorityOrAuthority(String auth1, String auth2);
}
```

```java
package pp.users.dao;


import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import pp.users.model.User;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query(value = """
            SELECT u
            FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.authorities
            WHERE u.username != :username
            """)
    List<User> findAllExcept(String username);

    @Query(value = """
            SELECT u
            FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.authorities
            WHERE u.username = :username
            """)
    User findByUsername(String username);

    void deleteByUsername(String username);
}
```

```java
package pp.users.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "role", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String authority;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authorities")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<User> userList;

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return authority;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringJoiner(", ", Role.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
                .add("id=" + id)
                .add("role='" + authority + "'")
                .toString();
    }
}
```

```java
package pp.users.model;


import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String department;
    @Column
    private int salary;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private byte age;
    @Column
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
    private byte enabledByte;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Role> authorities;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(Role role) {
        this.enabledByte = 1;
        this.authorities = new HashSet<>(List.of(role));
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return authorities.stream().anyMatch(a -> a.getAuthority().equals("ADMIN"));
    }

    public boolean isBoardMember() {
        return department.equals("board of directors");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { // StringBuilder внутри StringJoiner лучше ломбоковской конкатенации
        return new StringJoiner(", ", User.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
                .add("id=" + id)
                .add("username='" + username + "'")
                .add("password='" + password + "'")
                .add("name='" + name + "'")
                .add("lastName='" + lastName + "'")
                .add("department='" + department + "'")
                .add("salary=" + salary)
                .add("age=" + age)
                .add("email='" + email + "'")
                .add("enabled=" + enabledByte)
                .add("authorities=" + authorities)
                .toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabledByte == 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```java
package pp.users.service;

import pp.users.model.Role;

import java.util.Set;

public interface RoleService {
    Role findRoleByName(String name);

    Set<Role> findAdminRoleSet();

}
```

```java
package pp.users.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import pp.users.dao.RoleDao;
import pp.users.model.Role;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class RoleServiceImpl implements RoleService {
    private final RoleDao roleDao;

    public RoleServiceImpl(RoleDao roleDao) {
        this.roleDao = roleDao;
    }

    @Override
    public Role findRoleByName(String name) {
        return roleDao.findByAuthority(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Role> findAdminRoleSet() {
        return new HashSet<>(roleDao.findByAuthorityOrAuthority("USER", "ADMIN"));
    }
}
```

```java
package pp.users.service;


import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import pp.users.model.User;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserService {

    List<User> findAllExceptLoggedUser(String username);

    User findLoggedUser(Authentication authentication);

    void save(User user);

    void disableUserByUsername(String username);

    void enableUserByUsername(String username);

    void deleteUserByUsername(String username);

}
```

```java
package pp.users.service;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import pp.users.dao.UserDao;
import pp.users.model.User;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    private final UserDao userDao;

    public UserServiceImpl(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAllExceptLoggedUser(String username) {
        return userDao.findAllExcept(username);
    }

    @Override
    public User findLoggedUser(Authentication authentication) {
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        String loggedUserName = userDetails.getUsername();
        return userDao.findByUsername(loggedUserName);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(User user) {
        userDao.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void disableUserByUsername(String username) {
        User user = userDao.findByUsername(username);
        user.setEnabledByte((byte) 0);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void enableUserByUsername(String username) {
        User user = userDao.findByUsername(username);
        user.setEnabledByte((byte) 1);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteUserByUsername(String username) {
        userDao.deleteByUsername(username);
    }

}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>pp</groupId>
    <artifactId>user-management-system</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>user-management-system</name>
    <description>user-management-system</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.222</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
# connection properties
spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}

# initialization
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=true
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:/sql/data.sql
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:/sql/schema.sql

# logging
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

```sql
-- resources/sql/data.sql

-- inserting sample rows if empty

INSERT INTO users(username, password, name, last_name, department, salary, age, email, enabled)
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES ROW ('mickey_m', '$2y$10$i5SJc2KAriHGn7Dz2rRQHuQ3JfBxlzMaPVKP1YdEJCukryDY9NbVC',
              'Mickey', 'Mouse', 'sales', 180000, 95, 'mickey_m@gmail.com', 1),

             ROW ('donald_d', '$2y$10$E6SHpAN0aZGQ43HAO.TPiO27kDKXOGIgDc8xWDJdl2Prn2wzQzz5y',
              'Donald', 'Duck', 'information technology', 190000, 89, 'donald_d@outlook.com', 1),

             ROW ('scrooge_m', '$2a$10$ycVpl2BSD6o19wa3xXtmrOxc8qZjwoIk.e3oZqgQBOE.3NHANAYqa',
              'Scrooge', 'McDuck', 'board of directors', 700000, 76, 'scrooge@gmail.com', 1),

             ROW ('minerva_m', '$2y$10$sLgPImwI1WR5KZ98AFPHHut6MvbDoOdBnDC232oLRfejVsganoVyC',
              'Minerva', 'Mouse', 'sales', 180000, 95, 'minnie_m@outlook.com', 1),

             ROW ('goofus_d', '$2y$10$uRP3KtW/yviK.H2VazCECOEQdZxZUZNqHqy/bL4kZgmaBCdprNeE2',
              'Goofus', 'Dawg', 'information technology', 190000, 91, 'goofy@gmail.com', 1),

             ROW ('daisy_d', '$2a$10$mYfix0eIUMIWeTz6kM5.vuI/1demwzsvnY/mSgp5W6rcQVjc3Eyny',
              'Daisy', 'Duck', 'human resources', 165000, 86, 'daisy@outlook.com', 1))

         AS sample_rows

WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM users);

-- ensuring the required roles exist

INSERT IGNORE INTO roles(role)
VALUES ('USER'),
       ('ADMIN');

-- filling the @JoinTable: all users must be USERs

INSERT IGNORE INTO user_role
SELECT users.id, roles.id
FROM users
         JOIN roles ON roles.role = 'USER';

-- filling the @JoinTable: the first user must also be an ADMIN

INSERT IGNORE INTO user_role
SELECT users.id, roles.id
FROM users
         JOIN roles ON roles.role = 'ADMIN' ORDER BY users.id LIMIT 1;
```

```sql
-- resources/sql/schema.sql

CREATE TABLE users
(
    id         INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username   VARCHAR(15)  NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password   VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    name       VARCHAR(15)  NOT NULL,
    last_name  VARCHAR(25)  NOT NULL,
    department VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    salary     INT,
    age        TINYINT      NOT NULL,
    email      VARCHAR(50),
    enabled    TINYINT      NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE roles
(
    id   INT         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    role VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE user_role
(
    user_id  INT         NOT NULL,
    role_id  INT         NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, role_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles (id)
);
```

## Tests

```java
package pp.users.controller;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import pp.users.model.Role;
import pp.users.model.User;
import pp.users.service.RoleService;
import pp.users.service.UserService;

import java.util.Set;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@WebMvcTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@MockBean(RoleService.class)
class MyRestControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @MockBean
    UserService userService;
    @MockBean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    User mickey;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        mickey = new User();
        mickey.setUsername("mickey");
        mickey.setPassword("password");
        mickey.setName("Mickey");
        mickey.setLastName("Mouse");
        mickey.setDepartment("IT");
        mickey.setSalary(100_000);
        mickey.setEmail("mickey@gmail.com");
        mickey.setAge((byte) 100);
        mickey.setEnabledByte((byte) 1);
        mickey.setAuthorities(Set.of(new Role("USER")));

        when(passwordEncoder.encode(anyString())).thenReturn("password");
    }

    @Test
    void addUser() throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc.perform(post("/users")
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mickey))
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andReturn()
                .getResponse();
        User userFromResponse = objectMapper.readValue(response.getContentAsString(), User.class);
        assertThat(userFromResponse).isEqualTo(mickey);
        verify(userService, times(1)).save(mickey);
    }

    @Test
    void enableUserByUsername() throws Exception {
        mickey.setEnabledByte((byte) 0);
        mockMvc.perform(patch("/users/" + mickey.getUsername())
                        .header("patch_type", "enable"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
        verify(userService).enableUserByUsername(mickey.getUsername());
    }

    @Test
    void disableUserByUsername() throws Exception {
        mickey.setEnabledByte((byte) 1);
        mockMvc.perform(patch("/users/" + mickey.getUsername())
                        .header("patch_type", "disable"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
        verify(userService).disableUserByUsername(mickey.getUsername());
    }

    @Test
    void updateUser() throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc.perform(put("/users")
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mickey))
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .header("password_change", "false")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn()
                .getResponse();
        User userFromResponse = objectMapper.readValue(response.getContentAsString(), User.class);
        assertThat(userFromResponse).isEqualTo(mickey);
        verify(userService).save(mickey);
    }

    @Test
    void deleteUserByUsername() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(delete("/users/" + mickey.getUsername()))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
        verify(userService).deleteUserByUsername(mickey.getUsername());
    }
}
```

```java
package pp.users.dao;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import pp.users.model.Role;

import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;

@DataJpaTest
class RoleDaoTest {
    @Autowired
    RoleDao roleDao;
    static final String USER = "USER";
    static final String ADMIN = "ADMIN";

    @BeforeEach
    void addSampleRows() {
        roleDao.saveAll(List.of(new Role(USER), new Role(ADMIN)));
    }

    @AfterEach
    void clearRows() {
        roleDao.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    void findByAuthority() {
        assertThat(roleDao.findByAuthority(USER))
                .extracting(Role::getAuthority)
                .isEqualTo(USER);
    }

    @Test
    void findByAuthorityOrAuthority() {
        List<String> roleStrings = roleDao.findByAuthorityOrAuthority("USER", "ADMIN")
                .stream()
                .map(Role::getAuthority)
                .toList();
        assertThat(roleStrings.size()).isEqualTo(2);
        assertThat(roleStrings).asList().contains(USER, ADMIN);
    }
}
```

```java
package pp.users.dao;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import pp.users.model.User;

import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;

@DataJpaTest
class UserDaoTest {
    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;
    String MICKEY = "mickey";
    String DAISY = "daisy";

    @BeforeEach
    void addSampleUsers() {
        User mickey = new User();
        mickey.setUsername(MICKEY);
        mickey.setPassword("password");
        mickey.setName("Mickey");
        mickey.setLastName("Mouse");
        mickey.setDepartment("IT");
        mickey.setAge((byte) 100);

        User daisy = new User();
        daisy.setUsername(DAISY);
        daisy.setPassword("password");
        daisy.setName("Daisy");
        daisy.setLastName("Duck");
        daisy.setDepartment("HR");
        daisy.setAge((byte) 100);

        userDao.saveAll(List.of(mickey, daisy));
    }

    @AfterEach
    void clearUsers() {
        userDao.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    void findAllExcept() {
        List<String> usernames = userDao.findAllExcept(MICKEY).stream()
                .map(User::getUsername)
                .toList();
        assertThat(usernames.size()).isEqualTo(1);
        assertThat(usernames).asList().contains(DAISY);
    }

    @Test
    void findByUsername() {
        assertThat(userDao.findByUsername(MICKEY))
                .extracting(User::getUsername)
                .isEqualTo(MICKEY);
    }

    @Test
    void deleteByUsername() {
        userDao.deleteByUsername(MICKEY);
        List<String> usernames = userDao.findAll().stream()
                .map(User::getUsername)
                .toList();
        assertThat(usernames).asList().doesNotContain(MICKEY);
    }
}
```

```java
package pp.users.service;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import pp.users.dao.RoleDao;
import pp.users.model.Role;

import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class RoleServiceImplTest {
    @InjectMocks
    RoleServiceImpl roleService;
    @Mock
    RoleDao roleDao;
    static final String USER = "USER";
    static final String ADMIN = "ADMIN";

    @Test
    void findRoleByName() {
        when(roleDao.findByAuthority(USER)).thenReturn(new Role(USER));
        assertThat(roleService.findRoleByName(USER)).extracting(Role::getAuthority).isEqualTo(USER);
        verify(roleDao, times(1)).findByAuthority(USER);
    }

    @Test
    void findAdminRoleSet() {
        when(roleDao.findByAuthorityOrAuthority(USER, ADMIN))
                .thenReturn(List.of(new Role(USER), new Role(ADMIN)));
        List<String> adminRoles = roleService.findAdminRoleSet().stream()
                .map(Role::getAuthority)
                .toList();
        assertThat(adminRoles.size()).isEqualTo(2);
        assertThat(adminRoles).asList().contains(ADMIN, USER);
        verify(roleDao, times(1)).findByAuthorityOrAuthority(USER, ADMIN);
    }
}
```

```java
package pp.users.service;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import pp.users.dao.UserDao;
import pp.users.model.User;

import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class UserServiceImplTest {
    @InjectMocks
    UserServiceImpl userService;
    @Mock
    UserDao userDao;
    String mickey;
    User mickeyUser;
    String daisy;
    User daisyUser;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        mickey = "mickey";
        mickeyUser = new User();
        mickeyUser.setUsername(mickey);
        mickeyUser.setPassword("password");
        mickeyUser.setName("Mickey");
        mickeyUser.setLastName("Mouse");
        mickeyUser.setDepartment("IT");
        mickeyUser.setAge((byte) 100);

        daisy = "daisy";
        daisyUser = new User();
        daisyUser.setUsername(daisy);
        daisyUser.setPassword("password");
        daisyUser.setName("Daisy");
        daisyUser.setLastName("Duck");
        daisyUser.setDepartment("HR");
        daisyUser.setAge((byte) 100);
    }

    @Test
    void findAllExceptLoggedUser() {
        when(userDao.findAllExcept(mickey)).thenReturn(List.of(daisyUser));
        List<String> usernames = userService.findAllExceptLoggedUser(mickey).stream()
                .map(User::getUsername)
                .toList();
        assertThat(usernames).asList().doesNotContain(mickey);
        verify(userDao, times(1)).findAllExcept(mickey);
    }

    @Test
    void findLoggedUser() {
        when(userDao.findByUsername(mickey)).thenReturn(mickeyUser);
        Authentication authenticationMock = mock(Authentication.class);
        when(authenticationMock.getPrincipal()).thenReturn(mickeyUser);
        assertThat(userService.findLoggedUser(authenticationMock))
                .extracting(User::getUsername).isEqualTo(mickey);
        verify(userDao, times(1)).findByUsername(mickey);
    }

    @Test
    void save() {
        userService.save(mickeyUser);
        verify(userDao, times(1)).save(mickeyUser);
    }

    @Test
    void disableUserByUsername() {
        mickeyUser.setEnabledByte((byte) 1);
        when(userDao.findByUsername(mickey)).thenReturn(mickeyUser);
        userService.disableUserByUsername(mickey);
        assertThat(mickeyUser.getEnabledByte()).isEqualTo((byte) 0);
        verify(userDao, times(1)).findByUsername(mickey);
    }

    @Test
    void enableUserByUsername() {
        mickeyUser.setEnabledByte((byte) 0);
        when(userDao.findByUsername(mickey)).thenReturn(mickeyUser);
        userService.enableUserByUsername(mickey);
        assertThat(mickeyUser.getEnabledByte()).isEqualTo((byte) 1);
        verify(userDao, times(1)).findByUsername(mickey);
    }

    @Test
    void deleteUserByUsername() {
        userService.deleteUserByUsername(mickey);
        verify(userDao, times(1)).deleteByUsername(mickey);
    }
}
```

```
# test properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

## Docker

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN apk add --no-cache maven && \
    mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true

FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/target/user-management-system-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java", "-jar", "user-management-system-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

```yml
version: '2.1'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/users_db?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: pp_user
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: pp_user

  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: users_db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: pp_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pp_user
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
```