# User Management System: a web app for management of user records (Part II: Frontend)

Tags: javascript, html

***Note:** It's Part II of the User Management System project, focused on the frontend. See Part I [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/291087/user-management-system-a-web-app-for-management-of-user-records-part-i-backen).*

Here's the frontend part. I want to note that I realized even back then that copy-pasting a huge block of HTML into JS was a bad idea, but couldn't find a better solution without page reloads. I haven't practiced frontend for a while so I'm now even less likely to come up with one.

```css
/* resources/static/bs-extension.css */

@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
    .navbar {
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
    .order-1 {
        order: 0;
    }
}

.btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white !important;
    width: max-content;
}

.btn-outline-primary {
    color: #007bff !important;
}

.btn-outline-primary:hover {
    color: white !important;
}

.btn-outline-warning {
    color: #ffc107 !important;
}

.btn-outline-warning:hover {
    color: white !important;
}

.btn-outline-success {
    color: #28a745 !important;
}

.btn-outline-success:hover {
    color: white !important;
}

.btn-outline-danger {
    color: #dc3545 !important;
}

.btn-outline-danger:hover {
    color: white !important;
}

.btn-outline-secondary {
    color: #6c757d !important;
}

.btn-outline-secondary:hover {
    color: white !important;
}

.btn-group a:last-of-type {
    border-top-right-radius: 0.2rem !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.2rem !important;
}

#shuffler {
    width: 2.2rem;
    display: block;
    margin: 1rem auto 1rem auto;
    opacity: 0.6;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

#shuffler.rotate {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform: rotate(180deg)
}

fieldset {
    border: 1px solid
}

.dummy-card {
    width: 290px;
    height: 310px
}

.dummy-card div:first-of-type {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .03);
    height: 15%
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .dummy-card {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```js
// resources/static/script.js

// filtering of table rows
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#my-search-input").on('keyup', function () {
        let value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("tbody tr").filter(function () {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});

// shuffler
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#shuffler').on('click', function () {
        $('.col-md-1').toggleClass('order-1');
        $('.nav-tabs').toggleClass('justify-content-end');
        $('#my-search-input, #add-new-user, .modal-body, .form-control').toggleClass('text-right');
        $(this).toggleClass('rotate');
    });
});

// add/update
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('submit', 'form', async function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        let user = {
            id: $(this).find('[name=id]').val(),
            username: $(this).find('[name=username]').val(),
            password: $(this).find('[name=password]').val(),
            name: $(this).find('[name=name]').val(),
            lastName: $(this).find('[name=lastName]').val(),
            department: $(this).find('[name=department]').val(),
            salary: $(this).find('[name=salary]').val(),
            age: $(this).find('[name=age]').val(),
            email: $(this).find('[name=email]').val(),
            enabledByte: $(this).find('[name=enabledByte]').val(),
            authorities: JSON.parse($(this).find('[name=authorities]:checked').val() ||
                $(this).find('[name=authorities]').val())
        };

        let method = $(this).closest('div').attr('id') === 'add-new-user' ? 'POST' : 'PUT';

        let passwordChange = $(this).find('input[name=password]')
            .attr('type') !== 'hidden';

        const response = await fetch('/users', {
            method: `${method}`,
            headers: {
                ...getCsrfHeaders(),
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'password_change': `${passwordChange}`
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(user)
        });

        const data = await response.json();

        if (response.ok) {

            if ($(this).closest('div').attr('id') === 'add-new-user') {
                let usersAuthorities = '';

                for (let i = 0; i < user.authorities.length; i++) {
                    if (i !== 0) usersAuthorities += ' ';
                    usersAuthorities += user.authorities[i]['authority'].charAt(0);
                }

                $('tbody').append(
                    `<tr>
                         <td>${user.username}</td>
                         <td>${user.name}</td>
                         <td>${user.lastName}</td>
                         <td>${user.department}</td>                     
                         <td>${user.salary}</td>                     
                         <td>${user.age}</td>                     
                         <td>${user.email}</td>
                         <td>${usersAuthorities}</td> 
                         <td>+</td>
                         <td class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                               data-target="${'#update-modal-' + user.username}">Update
                            </a>
                            <div class="modal" id="${'update-modal-' + user.username}">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
                                    <div class="modal-content">

                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h3 class="modal-title text-center w-100">
                                                ${'Edit ' + user.name + ' ' + user.lastName + ' (' + user.username + ')'}
                                            </h3>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
                                            </button>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="modal-body text-left">
                                            <p class="text-left">
                                                For the sake of privacy, you are only allowed to change the user's department
                                                and salary. If you think ${user.name}'s personal info needs to be altered, please request them to do so
                                            </p>

                                            <form>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${data.id}">

                                                <input type="hidden" name="username"
                                                       value="${user.username}">

                                                <input type="hidden" name="password"
                                                       value="${data.password}">

                                                <input type="hidden" name="name" value="${user.name}">

                                                <input type="hidden" name="lastName"
                                                       value="${user.lastName}">

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="${user.username + '-department'}">Department: </label>
                                                    <select id="${user.username + '-department'}"
                                                            class="form-control" name="department">
                                                        <option ${user.department === 'accounting' ? 'selected' : ''}
                                                                value="accounting">Accounting
                                                        </option>
                                                        <option ${user.department === 'sales' ? 'selected' : ''}
                                                                value="sales">Sales
                                                        </option>
                                                        <option ${user.department === 'information technology' ? 'selected' : ''}
                                                                value="information technology">IT
                                                        </option>
                                                        <option ${user.department === 'human resources' ? 'selected' : ''}
                                                                value="human resources">HR
                                                        </option>
                                                        <option ${user.department === 'board of directors' ? 'selected' : ''}
                                                                value="board of directors">Board
                                                        </option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="${user.username + '-salary'}">Salary: </label>
                                                    <input id="${user.username + '-salary'}"
                                                           class="form-control" name="salary"
                                                           value="${user.salary}"
                                                           min="100000" aria-describedby="au-salary-help-block"
                                                           required/>
                                                    <small id="au-salary-help-block"
                                                           class="form-text text-muted">
                                                        100,000+
                                                    </small>
                                                </div>

                                                <input type="hidden" name="age" value="${user.age}">

                                                <input type="hidden" name="email" value="${user.email}">

                                                <input type="hidden" name="enabledByte"
                                                       value="${user.enabledByte}">

                                                <input type="hidden" name="authorities"
                                                       value='${JSON.stringify(user.authorities)}'/>

                                                <input class="btn btn-primary d-flex ml-auto" type="submit"
                                                       value="Submit">
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <a class="btn mx-1 btn-outline-warning">Disable</a>

                            <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal"
                               data-target="${'#delete-modal-' + user.username}">Delete
                            </a>

                            <div class="modal" id="${'delete-modal-' + user.username}">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">

                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h3 class="modal-title text-center w-100">
                                                Are you sure you want to delete ${user.name} ${user.lastName} (${user.username})?
                                            </h3>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
                                            </button>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <p>This action may not be easily reversed</p>

                                            <a class="btn btn-danger d-flex ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal">I am sure
                                            </a>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                         </td>
                    </tr>`);

                const submitButton = $(this).find('[type=submit]');

                const form = $(this);

                submitButton.removeClass('btn-primary')
                    .addClass('btn-success')
                    .attr('value', 'User added!')
                    .attr('type', 'button')
                    .click(() => $('[href="#users-table"]').tab('show'));

                setTimeout(function () {
                    submitButton.removeClass('btn-success')
                        .addClass('btn-primary')
                        .attr('value', 'Submit')
                        .attr('type', 'submit')
                        .off('click');
                    form.trigger('reset');
                }, 9000);

            } else if ($(this).closest('.modal').attr('id') === 'update-info-modal') {
                const listItems = $(this).closest('.card-body').find('ol').children();

                listItems.eq(0).find('span').text(user.username);
                listItems.eq(1).find('span').text(user.name);
                listItems.eq(2).find('span').text(user.lastName);
                listItems.eq(5).find('span').text(user.age);
                listItems.eq(6).find('span').text(user.email);
            } else if ($(this).closest('.modal').attr('id').startsWith('update-modal-')) {
                const children = $(this).closest('tr').children();

                children.eq(0).text(user.username);
                children.eq(1).text(user.name);
                children.eq(2).text(user.lastName);
                children.eq(3).text(user.department);
                children.eq(4).text(user.salary);
                children.eq(5).text(user.age);
                children.eq(6).text(user.email);
            }
        }

        $(this).closest('.modal').modal('hide');
    });
});

// disable
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tbody').on('click', 'td a.btn-outline-warning', async function () {
        let username = $(this).closest('tr').children().eq(0).text();

        const response = await fetch(`/users/${username}`, {
            method: 'PATCH',
            headers: {
                ...getCsrfHeaders(),
                'patch_type': 'disable'
            }
        });

        if (response.ok) {
            $(this).removeClass('btn-outline-warning')
                .addClass('btn-outline-success')
                .text('Enable')
                .parent().prev().text('-');
        }
    });
});

// enable
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tbody').on('click', 'td a.btn-outline-success', async function () {
        let username = $(this).closest('tr').children().eq(0).text();

        const response = await fetch(`/users/${username}`, {
            method: 'PATCH',
            headers: {
                ...getCsrfHeaders(),
                'patch_type': 'enable'
            }
        });

        if (response.ok) {
            $(this).removeClass('btn-outline-success')
                .addClass('btn-outline-warning')
                .text('Disable')
                .parent().prev().text('+');
        }
    });
});

// delete
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tbody').on('click', '.modal-body a.btn-danger', async function () {
        let row = $(this).closest('tr');
        let username = row.children().eq(0).text();

        const response = await fetch(`/users/${username}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: getCsrfHeaders()
        });

        if (response.ok) {
            row.remove();
        }
    });
});

function getCsrfHeaders() {
    let csrfToken = $('meta[name="_csrf"]').attr('content');
    let csrfHeaderName = $('meta[name="_csrf_header"]').attr('content');

    let headers = {};
    headers[csrfHeaderName] = csrfToken;
    return headers;
}
```

```html
<!-- resources/templates/home-page.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bs-extension.css"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar py-0 mb-3 text-light bg-dark shadow">
    <div class="nav-item">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <strong th:text="${loggedUser.username}"></strong>
            <span> with role(s): </span>
        </div>
        <span class="navbar-text" th:each="role, iter : ${loggedUser.authorities}"
              th:text="${role.authority} + ${iter.last ? '' : ', '}"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link m-1 text-light" href="/logout">Log out</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container mb-5 mw-100">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-1 px-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item" sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')">
                    <a th:class="'nav-link text-center' + ${loggedUser.isAdmin() ? ' active' : ''}" data-toggle="pill"
                       href="#admin-tab">Admin</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a th:class="'nav-link text-center' + ${!loggedUser.isAdmin() ? ' active' : ''}" data-toggle="pill"
                       href="#user-tab">User</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <img id="shuffler" src="/next.png" alt="an arrow"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-11 tab-content">
            <div id="admin-tab" th:class="'tab-pane' + ${loggedUser.isAdmin() ? ' active' : ''}">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#users-table">All Users</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#add-new-user">Add New User</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="users-table" class="tab-pane active table-responsive">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="my-search-input">A search box for filtering users</label>
                        <input class="form-control my-2" id="my-search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search...">

                        <table class="table table-hover text-center">
                            <thead class="bg-dark text-light">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Username</th>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Department</th>
                                <th scope="col">Salary</th>
                                <th scope="col">Age</th>
                                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                                <th scope="col">Role(s)</th>
                                <th scope="col">Enabled</th>
                                <th scope="col">Operations</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr th:each="user: ${users}">
                                <td th:text="${user.username}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${user.name}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${user.lastName}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${user.department}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${user.salary}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${user.age}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${user.email}"></td>
                                <td>
                                    <span th:each="role, iter : ${user.authorities}"
                                          th:text="${role.authority == 'USER' ? 'U' : (role.authority == 'ADMIN' ? 'A' : '')} + ${iter.last ? '' : ' '}"></span>
                                </td>
                                <td th:text="${user.isEnabled() ? '+' : '-'}"></td>

                                <td class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                                       th:data-target="${'#update-modal-' + user.username}">Update
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="modal" th:id="${'update-modal-' + user.username}">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
                                            <div class="modal-content">

                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h3 class="modal-title text-center w-100"
                                                        th:text="${'Edit ' + user.name + ' ' + user.lastName + ' (' + user.username + ')'}"></h3>
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="modal-body text-left">
                                                    <p th:text="'For the sake of privacy, you are only allowed to change the user\'s department ' +
                                                        'and salary. If you think ' + ${user.name} + '\'s personal info needs to be altered, please request them to do so'"></p>

                                                    <form>
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="${user.id}">

                                                        <input type="hidden" name="username"
                                                               th:value="${user.username}">

                                                        <input type="hidden" name="password"
                                                               th:value="${user.password}">

                                                        <input type="hidden" name="name" th:value="${user.name}">

                                                        <input type="hidden" name="lastName"
                                                               th:value="${user.lastName}">

                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label th:for="${user.username + '-department'}">Department: </label>
                                                            <select th:id="${user.username + '-department'}"
                                                                    class="form-control" name="department">
                                                                <option th:selected="${user.department == 'accounting'}"
                                                                        value="accounting">Accounting
                                                                </option>
                                                                <option th:selected="${user.department == 'sales'}"
                                                                        value="sales">Sales
                                                                </option>
                                                                <option th:selected="${user.department == 'information technology'}"
                                                                        value="information technology">IT
                                                                </option>
                                                                <option th:selected="${user.department == 'human resources'}"
                                                                        value="human resources">HR
                                                                </option>
                                                                <option th:selected="${user.department == 'board of directors'}"
                                                                        value="board of directors">Board
                                                                </option>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label th:for="${user.username + '-salary'}">Salary: </label>
                                                            <input th:id="${user.username + '-salary'}"
                                                                   class="form-control" name="salary"
                                                                   th:value="${user.salary}"
                                                                   min="100000" aria-describedby="au-salary-help-block"
                                                                   required/>
                                                            <small id="au-salary-help-block"
                                                                   class="form-text text-muted">
                                                                100,000+
                                                            </small>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <input type="hidden" name="age" th:value="${user.age}">

                                                        <input type="hidden" name="email" th:value="${user.email}">

                                                        <input type="hidden" name="enabledByte"
                                                               th:value="${user.enabledByte}">

                                                        <input type="hidden" th:name="authorities"
                                                               th:value="${@jsonify.apply(user.authorities)}"/>

                                                        <input class="btn btn-primary d-flex ml-auto" type="submit"
                                                               value="Submit">
                                                    </form>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <a th:class="'btn mx-1 ' + ${user.isEnabled() ? 'btn-outline-warning' : 'btn-outline-success'}"
                                       th:text="${user.isEnabled() ? 'Disable' : 'Enable'}"></a>

                                    <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal"
                                       th:data-target="${'#delete-modal-' + user.username}">Delete
                                    </a>

                                    <div class="modal" th:id="${'delete-modal-' + user.username}">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                                            <div class="modal-content">

                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h3 class="modal-title text-center w-100"
                                                        th:text="${'Are you sure you want to delete ' + user.name + ' ' + user.lastName + ' (' + user.username + ')?'}"></h3>
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    <p>This action may not be easily reversed</p>

                                                    <a class="btn btn-danger d-flex ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal">I am
                                                        sure
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div id="add-new-user" class="tab-pane">
                        <h4 class="display-4">Fill in the forms</h4>
                        <form th:object="${newUser}">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="*{id}">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nu-username">Username: </label>
                                <input id="nu-username" class="form-control" name="username" type="text" pattern="\w+"
                                       minlength="2" maxlength="15" aria-describedby="username-help-block" required>
                                <small id="username-help-block" class="form-text text-muted">
                                    2-15 characters. Only letters, digits, and underscores are allowed
                                </small>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nu-password">Password: </label>
                                <input id="nu-password" class="form-control" name="password" type="password"
                                       minlength="5" aria-describedby="password-help-block" required/>
                                <small id="password-help-block" class="form-text text-muted">
                                    5+ characters
                                </small>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nu-name">Name: </label>
                                <input id="nu-name" class="form-control" name="name" type="text" minlength="2"
                                       maxlength="15" aria-describedby="name-help-block" required/>
                                <small id="name-help-block" class="form-text text-muted">
                                    2-15 characters
                                </small>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nu-last-name">Last name: </label>
                                <input id="nu-last-name" class="form-control" name="lastName" type="text"
                                       minlength="2" maxlength="25" aria-describedby="last-name-help-block" required/>
                                <small id="last-name-help-block" class="form-text text-muted">
                                    2-15 characters
                                </small>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nu-departments">Department: </label>
                                <select id="nu-departments" class="form-control" name="department" required>
                                    <option class="dropdown-item" value="accounting">Accounting</option>
                                    <option class="dropdown-item" value="sales">Sales</option>
                                    <option class="dropdown-item" value="information technology">IT</option>
                                    <option class="dropdown-item" value="human resources">HR</option>
                                    <option class="dropdown-item" value="board of directors">Board</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nu-salary">Salary: </label>
                                <input id="nu-salary" class="form-control" name="salary" type="number"
                                       min="100000" aria-describedby="salary-help-block" required/>
                                <small id="salary-help-block" class="form-text text-muted">
                                    100,000+
                                </small>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nu-age">Age: </label>
                                <input id="nu-age" class="form-control" name="age" type="number" min="18"
                                       max="127" aria-describedby="age-help-block" required/>
                                <small id="age-help-block" class="form-text text-muted">
                                    18-127
                                </small>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nu-email">Email: </label>
                                <input id="nu-email" class="form-control" name="email" type="email"
                                       pattern="[A-Za-z._-]+@[a-z]{1,}\.[a-z]{2,4}"
                                       aria-describedby="email-help-block" required/>
                                <small id="email-help-block" class="form-text text-muted">
                                    Any valid email address
                                </small>
                            </div>

                            <input type="hidden" name="enabledByte" th:value="*{enabledByte}"/>

                            <fieldset class="p-2 mb-3">
                                <legend class="w-auto px-2">Privileges</legend>
                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                    <label for="user" class="form-check-label mr-2">User: </label>
                                    <input id="user" class="form-check-input" name="authorities" type="radio"
                                           th:value="${@jsonify.apply(newUser.authorities)}"
                                           checked/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                    <label for="admin" class="form-check-label mr-2">User + Admin: </label>
                                    <input id="admin" class="form-check-input" name="authorities" type="radio"
                                           th:value="${@jsonify.apply(adminRoleSet)}"/>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>

                            <input class='btn btn-primary' type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="user-tab" th:class="'tab-pane' + ${!loggedUser.isAdmin() ? ' active' : ''}"
                 th:object="${loggedUser}">
                <h4 class="display-4 text-center mb-4">Your employee card</h4>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">

                    <div class="dummy-card shadow my-auto">
                        <div></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card shadow-lg">
                        <div class="card-header text-center text-secondary">
                            <h4 class="d-inline font-weight-bold" th:text="*{name + ' ' + lastName}"></h4>
                            <span th:text="*{' (' + username + ')'}"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <ol>
                                <li><strong>Username: </strong><span th:text="*{username}"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li><strong>Name: </strong><span th:text="*{name}"></span></li>
                                <li><strong>Lastname: </strong><span th:text="*{lastName}"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li><strong>Department: </strong><span
                                        th:text="*{department}"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li><strong>Salary: </strong><span th:text="*{salary}"></span></li>
                                <li><strong>Age: </strong><span th:text="*{age}"></span></li>
                                <li><strong>Email: </strong><span th:text="*{email}"></span></li>
                                <li><strong>Role(s): </strong>
                                    <span th:each="role, iter : ${loggedUser.authorities}"
                                          th:text="${role.authority == 'USER' ? 'U' : (role.authority == 'ADMIN' ? 'A' : '')} + ${iter.last ? '' : ' '}"></span>
                                </li>
                            </ol>

                            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary my-1" data-toggle="modal"
                               data-target="#update-info-modal">
                                Edit info
                            </a>
                            <div class="modal" id="update-info-modal">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
                                    <div class="modal-content">

                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h3 class="modal-title text-center w-100">Edit your info</h3>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <p th:text="'Unfortunately, you are not allowed to directly change your department and salary. ' +
                                        'If you wish to alter this information, consider getting in touch with ' +
                                        ${loggedUser.isBoardMember() ? 'the shareholders' : 'your superiors'}"></p>
                                            <form>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="*{id}"/>

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="username">Username: </label>
                                                    <input id="username" class="form-control" name="username"
                                                           th:value="*{username}" pattern="\w+" min="2"
                                                           max="15" aria-describedby="uu-username-help-block" required/>
                                                    <small id="uu-username-help-block" class="form-text text-muted">
                                                        2-15 characters. Only letters, digits, and underscores are
                                                        allowed
                                                    </small>
                                                </div>

                                                <input type="hidden" name="password" th:value="*{password}"/>

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="name">Name: </label>
                                                    <input id="name" class="form-control" name="name" th:value="*{name}"
                                                           min="5"
                                                           aria-describedby="uu-name-help-block" required/>
                                                    <small id="uu-name-help-block" class="form-text text-muted">
                                                        5+ characters
                                                    </small>

                                                </div>

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="last-name">Last name: </label>
                                                    <input id="last-name" class="form-control" name="lastName"
                                                           th:value="*{lastName}" min="2" max="15"
                                                           aria-describedby="uu-last-name-help-block"
                                                           required/>
                                                    <small id="uu-last-name-help-block" class="form-text text-muted">
                                                        2-15 characters
                                                    </small>
                                                </div>

                                                <input type="hidden" name="department" th:value="*{department}"/>

                                                <input type="hidden" name="salary" th:value="*{salary}"/>

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="age">Age: </label>
                                                    <input id="age" class="form-control" name="age" th:value="*{age}"
                                                           min="18" max="127" aria-describedby="uu-age-help-block"
                                                           required/>
                                                    <small id="uu-age-help-block" class="form-text text-muted">
                                                        18-127
                                                    </small>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="email">Email: </label>
                                                    <input id="email" class="form-control" name="email"
                                                           th:value="*{email}"
                                                           pattern="[A-Za-z._-]+@[a-z]{1,}\.[a-z]{2,4}"
                                                           aria-describedby="uu-email-help-block" required/>
                                                    <small id="uu-email-help-block" class="form-text text-muted">
                                                        Any valid email address
                                                    </small>
                                                </div>

                                                <input type="hidden" name="enabledByte" th:value="*{enabledByte}"/>

                                                <input type="hidden" name="authorities"
                                                       th:value="${@jsonify.apply(loggedUser.authorities)}"/>

                                                <input class="btn btn-primary d-flex ml-auto" type="submit"
                                                       value="Submit">
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="modal"
                               data-target="#update-password-modal">
                                Change password
                            </a>
                            <div class="modal" id="update-password-modal">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h3 class="modal-title text-center w-100">Update your password</h3>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <form>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="*{id}"/>

                                                <input type="hidden" name="username" th:value="*{username}"/>

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="password">Your new password: </label>
                                                    <input id="password" class="form-control" name="password"
                                                           type="password" min="5"
                                                           aria-describedby="uu-password-help-block"
                                                           required/>
                                                    <small id="uu-password-help-block" class="form-text text-muted">
                                                        5+ characters
                                                    </small>
                                                </div>

                                                <input type="hidden" name="name" th:value="*{name}"/>

                                                <input type="hidden" name="lastName" th:value="*{lastName}"/>

                                                <input type="hidden" name="department" th:value="*{department}"/>

                                                <input type="hidden" name="salary" th:value="*{salary}"/>

                                                <input type="hidden" name="age" th:value="*{age}"/>

                                                <input type="hidden" name="email" th:value="*{email}"/>

                                                <input type="hidden" name="enabledByte" th:value="*{enabledByte}"/>

                                                <input type="hidden" name="authorities"
                                                       th:value="${@jsonify.apply(loggedUser.authorities)}"/>

                                                <input class="btn btn-primary d-flex ml-auto" type="submit"
                                                       value="Submit">
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="dummy-card shadow my-auto">
                        <div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer class="p-1 bg-secondary text-right">
    <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/next" title="next icons" class="text-light">Next icon created by
        Roundicons - Flaticon</a>
</footer>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<script src="/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'll paste just one picture. See more screenshots in [the repo's](https://github.com/NadChel/user-management-system) README

[image: admin's user table]